# Metadata Service Test Class Error

Tags: metadata

I'm still new to Metadata Services and I'm writing a test class for it. I tried what I have read on the web but I'm still getting problems on it. Could you please help me please? I'm so stuck on this.

This is part of the class that I'm trying to cover in test class:

```
    public static void syncStagesNames(){

        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
        // Read Custom Field
        MetadataService.CustomField customField = PGSet_BatchInputSettingsController.getMetadataFields(service, 'ASPHPPADDON__Batch_Donation_Form__c.ASPHPPADDON__StagePicklist__c');
        MetadataService.CustomField customFieldOppStage = PGSet_BatchInputSettingsController.getMetadataFields(service, 'Opportunity.StageName');

        System.debug('customField :'+customField);
        System.debug('customFieldOppStage :'+customFieldOppStage);

        Set<String> oppStage = new Set<String>();
        for ( MetadataService.PicklistValue picklistValue : customField.picklist.picklistValues ) {
            oppStage.add(picklistValue.fullName);
        }

        if(oppStage.size() > 0){
            for(MetadataService.PicklistValue batchPicklistVal : customFieldOppStage.picklist.picklistValues){
                if(!oppStage.contains(batchPicklistVal.fullName)){
                    MetadataService.PicklistValue addVal = new MetadataService.PicklistValue();
                    addVal.fullName= batchPicklistVal.fullName;
                    addVal.default_x = batchPicklistVal.default_x;
                    customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(addVal); 
                }
            }
        }
        //Update Custom Field 
        MetadataServiceExamples.handleSaveResults(service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField })[0]);

}
```

The above code is a method from the controller I was creating. I made this test class:

```
@isTest 
public class ControllerTest {
    static testMethod void testSettingsController() {
      PGSet_BatchInputSettingsController.syncStagesNames();
    }
}
```

but it gave me this error: 
*System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts*

What should be done here? or how should I code my test class to cover this method?

Comment: They already provide MetadataServiceTest class. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: Hi, I added the MetadataServiceTest class but it still didnt cover so I thought should I add or create another?

Comment: I suppose it will cover MetadataService class completely if you haven't customize it. Also it's hard to understand right now as it is not clear what is the problem you are facing in creating your own test methods.

Comment: The syncStagesNames() is a method from a controller I created and it's what I am trying to cover in the test class:                                                                         '@isTest 
 public class ControllerTest {
    static testMethod void testSettingsController() {
        PGSet_BatchInputSettingsController.syncStagesNames();
    }
}'  ... but it gave me an error stating, System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Comment: hi, sorry. I've updated the description above instead. I hope you can help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the Metadata API, via the Apex Metadata Service library, is a callout. You cannot make a callout in test context. Instead, you're required to provide a mock, a class that generates a pseudo-response, since you cannot actually connect to a remote server in test context.

In this case, you'll need a class implementing [WebServiceMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_webservicemock.htm#!), because the Metadata API is connecting to a SOAP service. (More on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_soap_callouts)).

Your test class will call `Test.setMock()` with an instance of your mock class prior to calling `syncStagesNames()`. This will ensure it is in place and able to respond to outbound connections, rather than having the error you observe be thrown.

Normally, you should expect to be making assertions about the behavior of your code in your unit tests. In this case, assertions are challenging because your code cannot perform its real work (updating metadata) in a test context. What you can do, however, is have your Mock class retain the values with which it is called, so that you can make assertions about the updates your class attempts to perform, and validate that they are what you expected.

This is especially challenging in the case of this class because its entire functionality is dependent upon your org's metadata, which means your test class cannot insert tailored data to observe the behavior of specific code paths. You'll require a fairly complex mock class that's designed to return tailored data to your metadata queries, ensuring that each code path is executed and that you have an expected result set you can validate. Factoring this method into pieces may prove necessary.

Comment: Hello David, Thank you for your explanation and I'm sorry if my question is quiet unclear. I wasnt sure how to ask about the problem because I'm also confused with it myself- hehe. Probably, I just want to confirm if I need to create a mock class or not.

Comment: Yes, you do need to create a mock class.